# Counting number of plants in area using images from UAV?

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, density, feature-extraction, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

How do I count the number of pineapple plants in a 1-hectare block?

I have heard of these algorithms but I don't know how to do it.

I'm still a newbie of QGIS, ArcGIS and ENVI. I have the NIR, RGB, Red Edge images of the said area. Can anyone teach me how to do it?

I have access to eCognition developer but I'm still new to this software.

[image: Pineapple_Plants]

Comment: http://www.suasnews.com/2016/10/birds-ai-will-demo-advanced-computer-vision-software-ces-2017-ai-startup-selected-participate-hollands-startup-pavilion/ Maybe get in touch with these guys their picture looks the same...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make NDVI map and calculate the green areas with raster calculator then create 20-30 of 5 m random line. Go to field and count the plants on those random lines. After that you can generalize your calculations.